# Best way to achieve exclusion matrix via query

Tags: sql, matrix, sql-server-2000

What is the best way to achieve this exclusion matrix via query.

There are fixed number of products in a table and idea is if a product is sold to a customer (represented by row), the other products (columns) may or may not be sold based on the rule matrix below. The aim is to get products code which are allowed to sold for any given sold product code.

```
ProductCode|MRLSPN|MRLSPPN|MRLSDF|MRLSPDF|LGS|LGP|HOBN|HODF|HVO|HVOF
MRLSPN     |No    |No     |No    |No     |No |Yes|No  |No  |No |No  
MRLSPPN    |No    |No     |No    |No     |No |No |No  |No  |No |No  
MRLSDF     |No    |No     |No    |No     |No |Yes|No  |No  |No |No  
MRLSPDF    |No    |No     |No    |No     |No |No |No  |No  |No |No  
LGS        |No    |No     |No    |No     |No |Yes|No  |No  |No |No  
LGP        |Yes   |No     |Yes   |No     |No |No |No  |No  |No |No
HOBN       |No    |No     |No    |No     |Yes|Yes|No  |No  |No |No  
HODF       |No    |No     |No    |No     |Yes|Yes|No  |No  |No |No  
HVO        |Yes   |Yes    |Yes   |Yes    |Yes|Yes|Yes |Yes |No |No  
HVOF       |Yes   |Yes    |Yes   |Yes    |Yes|Yes|Yes |Yes |No |No
```

Ready by row across columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you change your format from a matrix to an association table like

Table AdditionalProducts:
   SoldProductCode
   AdditionalProductCode

So your table would look like

```
SoldProdCode, Additional ProdCode
MRLSPN, LGP
MRLSDF, LGP
```

Now you can simply run a query to say

```
SELECT AdditionalProductCode
FROM AdditionalProducts
WHERE SoldProductcode='MRLSPN'
```

**Edit**

Another benefit of this approach is that what if you give special discounts if you buy MRLSPN you get LGP at 10% off and if you buy MRLSDF you might get 15$ off. With this model you can extend the association table to include additional attributes. This may or may not apply to your model.

Comment: add a composite primary key to that table, or at least a unique key

Comment: You should definetly have a PK on the table. Either a composite key or adding an identity column with a unique key (I prefer the composite key personally in this case where there is no additional information to be stored)

Comment: Thanks Guys - This is what I got:

CREATE TABLE dbo.ProductMapping (
 ProductID   int         NOT NULL,
 ProductCode varchar(30) NOT NULL
) 

CREATE TABLE dbo.ProductMatrix (
 ProductSoldID      int NOT NULL, -¬
 ProductCanBeSoldID int NOT NULL, -- unique
 IsAllowed          int NOT NULL  -- 0/1
)

-- Query
SELECT ProductCanBeSold = lpa.ProductCode
FROM dbo.ProductMapping lpc
INNER JOIN dbo.ProductMatrix lsm ON lpc.Productint= lsm.ProductSoldID AND lsm.IsAllowed = 1
INNER JOIN dbo.ProductMapping lpa ON lsm.ProductCanBeSoldID = lpa.ProductID
WHERE lpc.ProductCode='MRLSPN'

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee no more than 32 columns, you can implement using an int (32 bits) as a bit-flag field. But a many-to-many relationship will be more flexible.

Create a many-to-many mapping table, ProductCode2ProductCodeMapping

```
CREATE TABLE ProductCode2ProductCodeMapping
(
   ProductCodeId int,
   AllowedProductCodeId int
)
```

With a composite primary key using both those columns.

Then insert a row for every product and related product.

Then simply query as:

```
SELECT AllowedProductCodeId 
FROM ProductCode2ProductCodeMapping
WHERE ProductCodeId = @myProductCodeId
```

If you don't have integer Id's for products you can either add them or use the char productCode instead (I'd prefer the former)

Answer (score 0):

It's a many-to-many link table:

```
Sold   CanBeSold
----   ---------
MRLSPN LGP
MRLSDF LGP
…
```

, and a query:

```
SELECT  CanBeSold
FROM    matrix
WHERE   Sold = @Product
```